# How do you create a random range, but exclude a specific number?

Tags: python, if-statement, random, while-loop, range

I have the following code:

```
while True:
    if var_p1 != "0":
        break
    else:
        import random
        var_p1 = random.randint(-5,5)
```

I want the loop to repeat until `var_p1` equals anything but zero. However, I get zero all the time. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you understand the difference between "0" and 0 ? At least in Python ?

Comment: Not really.... I have been teaching myself slowly using online tutorials etc. However I do not recall the difference being properly explained...

Comment: Hmm. I think that part is left for the user to understand. Anyways remember this, anything within single/double quotes is a string in python.Eg : x = "1234" is a string ( not integer/number) but x = 1234 is integer value (number). If you aren't clear yet then I will answer with further explanation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Answering the question in the title, not the real problem (which was answered by Daniel Roseman):

**How do you create a random range, but exclude a specific number?**

Using [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice):

```
import random
allowed_values = list(range(-5, 5+1))
allowed_values.remove(0)

# can be anything in {-5, ..., 5} \ {0}:
random_value = random.choice(allowed_values)
```

Comment: i don't see the reason for the +1 after the 5. Why couldn't you have just used (-5,5) ?

Comment: You need `range(5,6)` as range does exclude the right boundary. See [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range)

Comment: This code makes the optimal number of calls to a `random` function, so it's (probably) the most efficient, assuming that `allowed_values` doesn't get generated in a loop (eg, if it's generated as a local variable in a randomizer function).

Answer (score 5):

`"0" != 0`.

You are comparing against a string, but `randint` gives you an integer.

Answer (score 4):

Well you check against a string to break the loop. So use:

```
if var_p1 != 0:
```

instead of:

```
if var_p1 != "0":
```

A memory efficient way to generate from `a` to `b` but not including a value `c` is:

```
r = random.randint(a, b - 1)
if r >= c:
    r += 1
```

This way, in the first step we'll generate a random int between `a` and `c - 1` or between `c` and `b - 1`. In the second case we increment by one and we get a random number between `c + 1` and `b`. It's easy to see that each number between `a..(c - 1)` and `(c + 1)..b` has the same probability.

Comment: I _was_ going to suggest this approach, but I figured using `choice` was better since it avoids the `if`... but Moose beat me to submitting an answer. :)

Comment: Indeed, and as I mentioned in the comment on Moose's answer, if you create it locally in the function that generates the random numbers that's very wasteful. Typically, I'd create it (as a tuple) in the global context, just above the definition of the randomizer function.

Comment: @JuniorCompressor I guess choice has the advantage that each element gets drawn with the same probability. Irritatingly, the documentation does not state this.

Comment: @moose Yes both methods give the same probability. I think choice is surely very good when your data don't follow a pattern and you don't have problem with the space. Otherwise, you could end up storing a million ints for selecting a random one because you need only one exception.

Answer (score 3):

Your code fails because you're comparing an integer to a string. There are other problems with your code:

- You have an `import` statement inside a loop.
- There's no telling how many times your loop will run.

Here is a loop-free way to randomly generate a non-zero integer from -5 to +5, inclusive.

```
import random
x = random.randint(1, 5)
if random.randrange(2) == 1:
  x = -x
```

This code is guaranteed to call `random.randrange` exactly twice.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that `import` should be at the top of the script. Putting it inside a loop is not an error, per se, and subsequent attempts to import the same module will have no effect, but it's still poor style.

Comment: Yes, there's no way to know how many times the loop in the OP's code will run. However, the expected value is 1.1 loops per number returned, i.e. to return 1000 numbers 1100 random numbers will typically be generated. So although the OP's algorithm's runtime is non-deterministic, actually it's not that bad, since both your algorithm and JuniorCompressor's both need to generate 2000 random numbers to return 1000 results.

Comment: Yes, you're right. An expected value of 1.1 is better than a guaranteed value of 2.

Comment: Dear people of the future: JuniorCompressor's code has changed so my previous remark no longer applies to it. :)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative method, just pick one random element from the array, [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5].  Guaranteed to work with just one call.